# Check Box AutoSum with Javascript & PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

I wanted to put a checkbox autosum on my website so that anyone who check a box and submit, the values (Points) of those check box are automatically added to my total sum (on home page actually)
I have found this code so far for java script.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td> <input name="sum_m_1" value="25" type="checkbox" id="sum_m_1" onclick="UpdateCost()"> </td>
    <td> ResponseOption_1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input name="sum_m_2" value="15" type="checkbox" id="sum_m_2" onclick="UpdateCost()"> </td>
    <td> ResponseOption_2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="">
```

With JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateCost() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
  for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
    gn = 'sum_m_'+i;
    elem = document.getElementById(gn);
    if (elem.checked == true) { sum += Number(elem.value); }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalcost' ).value = sum.toFixed(2);
}
window.onload=UpdateCost
</script>
```

This will add up the values but i wanted to add by checking check boxes --> Submit --> collect the data --> add to my main total.

Any helps would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple changes:

- Add a button "calculate cost".
- Removed the onclick events from the checkboxes and added the onclick event to the button instead.

Note that "window.onload=UpdateCost" is still there because what you want ideally is for the total cost to be displayed properly as 0.00 when the page loads.

**HTML**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td> <input name="sum_m_1" value="25" type="checkbox" id="sum_m_1"> </td>
    <td> ResponseOption_1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input name="sum_m_2" value="15" type="checkbox" id="sum_m_2"> </td>
    <td> ResponseOption_2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="">
<input type="button" value="update cost" onclick="UpdateCost();">
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateCost() {
      var sum = 0;
      var gn, elem;
      for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
        gn = 'sum_m_'+i;
        elem = document.getElementById(gn);
        if (elem. checked == true) { sum += Number(elem. value); }
      }
      document.getElementById('totalcost' ).value = sum.toFixed(2);
    }
    window.onload=UpdateCost
</script>
```

Hope that's the kind of thing you wanted, let me me know what you think.

Comment: Hi, thanks ... yeaa this is what i want but actually i want that total sum to be saved, so next guest who comes and update it will just add up on that value.
For eg.
1-Main value start = 0
2- Guest 1: add 40
3- Main value = 40
4- Guest 2: add 60
5- Main value 40+60=100

I hope i have explained it well.
your help will be much appreciated.;)

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure what you mean, or what the intention for this form is but basically if you want to save data so another user can see it and update it, you'd basically either use AJAX or the usual form action to send the form data to a PHP script. The PHP script would save the data in some way (either in a file, or in a database). The page the user views with the form would have a thing saying "total" or whatever, you'd echo the value using PHP.

Comment: Yeaa okay... I mean the exact thing that you explained . i want the total sum that a user sumbits , to be saved in my data base so that next user will see the updated totall and he could also update on that value. but the thing is i not sure how to code these all connected together... please help

Comment: Do you already have a database set up? If so, what's the structure like?

Comment: okay the setup of the database wouldnt be a problem. ill set up a mysql database, is that right ? then i can connect to my database with user pass with php... if im wrong correct me.

Comment: Yeah set up the database and a PHP script for taking the values the user has input and inserting them into the database, then change the HTML so that the <input> elements are with in a <form> element, then set the "action" of the form to that PHP script, then change the "button" input to a "submit" input. The user will then be able to click the button and their values will be added to the database.